# Dotnet executable отсутствует после установки на Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, rider, apt

Недавно я решил перейти с Windows на Linux и выбрал в качестве старта Ubuntu. Я установил все нужные для меня программы и приступил к установке Rider, как IDE для работы с C#.
Изначально всё было хорошо, однако, после очередного обновления и использования команды apt autoremove (полагаю, что она могла повлиять на ситуацию) по неизвестной мне причине по пути dotnet/dotnet исчезла executable dotnet sdk.
[image: Rider1]
[image: Rider2]
Переустановка через apt или apt-get по тому, как описано в документации не поменяло ситуацию, поэтому мой вопрос: можно ли скачать этот sdk executable, создать папку dotnet и поместить его туда?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, бедолаги-программисты на линуксе, желающие писать на шарпах. Решением данной проблемы являлось скачка не через apt, а через snap:

```
sudo snap install dotnet-sdk --classic
```

Увы, dotnet --list-sdks также будет выводить вам пустой список,а значит скорее всего CLI работать не будет, однако, по пути snap будет лежать заветный sdk, который ваше IDE (во всяком случае моё - Rider) найдёт без проблем.